# $\int_0^1 e^{x^2}(2x-a)dx=0$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

$\int_0^1 e^{x^2}(2x-a)dx=0$
 where $a$ is any real number then predict the range of $a$ or find its value.

My approach: $\int_0^1 e^{x^2}2xdx=(e-1)$

Can't integrate  $a\int_0^1 e^{x^2}dx$.

Comment: this is an error function, $\text{erf}(1)$

Comment: if you differentiate with respect to $a$, the derivative is strictly negative so there is only one solution, which is $\frac{e-1}{\int_0^1 e^{x^2}dx}$ where, (almost) as said Alex, the denominator is proportional to the imaginary error function $erfi$ so I guess you can't expect a better expression than $\frac{e-1}{\frac{2}{\sqrt(\pi)}erfi(1)}$

Answer (score 1):

You need not integrate the other function. You can solve it by using graphical method. Now if you differentiate $e^{x^2}$. You will find that the slope of this curve is less than the slope of the curve $y=e^x$.which means $y=e^x$ has a greater area than $y=e^{x^2}$ in $[0,1]$. This is a graphical observation. Now by integrating $y=e^x$ in $[0,1]$. You get ${{e-1}\over a}<e-1$ or $a>1$ or $a<0$. Similarly area under the curve $y=1$ less than the area of $y=e^{x^2}$ from this the interval of a will come out to be $(0,e-1)$. Again area under $y=e^{-x}$ is less than area under the curve $y=e^{x^2}$. From there you will get $0<a<e$. Note that the above method is just an approximation. You can find more number of intervals by thinking of some more functions like $y=e$?

In that case $a<0$ or $a>1-{1\over e}$ will be solution. Now from the above intervals chose the most accurate interval in which a will likely belong to.